# retrieve size of data copied with hadoop distcp

Tags: hadoop, size, distcp, qubole

I am running a hadoop distcp command as below:

```
hadoop distcp src-loc target-loc
```

I want to know the size of the data copied by running this command.
I am planning to run the command on Qubole.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Run following command

```
hadoop dfs -dus -h target-loc
```

225.2 G  target-loc

It will print the human readable summary for the target-loc.